# history and router doesn't work with electron

Tags: reactjs, react-router, electron

I am using the `createHashHistory` for history with the router and creating an exe with the electron. For the redirection, I am using the `history.push()`.

The push is replacing the whole location instead of just the path after the `#`.

Initial location :

```
"file:///C:/AppData/Local/Programs/ReactApp/resources/app/build/index.html#/"
```

Location after push of '/home' :

```
"file:///C:/home"
```

Could someone please help me with getting it to work. I am using the same code for both the web application and the electron.

Comment: I would suggest using express as a server for the react. that would be better from file protocol access. And I personally have used it (express + electron + react) app with no issue with history or routing.

Comment: @AneesIjaz. If I am building an exe for distribution, do you suggest using express on each system, instead of the file access?

Comment: well the idea when your app starts , it triggers the express service on a specific port that of course redirects requests to react build. and the electron window loads the view via localhost on port you have assigned.

Comment: The express server configuration can also be packed with in the same asar archive. so on start you app starts the express server using spawn and then your app access it via url and port. simple.[Electron JS + React JS + Express JS - Keshav Agrawal - Medium](https://medium.com/@keshavagrawal/electron-js-react-js-express-js-b0fb2aa8233f)